# How to move column value to new column in Postgresql?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

i would like to create table from

```
SELECT 
a.value_text, 
a.value_free_text,
a.value_date,
a.value_number
FROM survey_user_input_line a 
LEFT JOIN survey_label b on b.id = a.value_suggested
WHERE a.survey_id = %s
ORDER BY question_id, a.user_input_id,  id, value_suggested_row
```

[image]

to

[image]

can anybody tell me how to code it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use a chained call to `COALESCE`, making sure to cast all columns to a common data type (text makes the most sense here):

```sql
SELECT *, COALESCE(value_text, value_free_text, value_date::text,
                   value_number::text) AS all_value
FROM yourTable;
```